# Adding OpenAI's GPT3 to a Unity project?

Tags: unity, c#, ai

I have a text-based project and it has a slot open for OpenAI's GPT3 model. My project has a terminal module where the user receives emails, I want to go a step further and allow the user to respond to such emails and get some unique response.

Here is a rundown of how I want it to work: User receives "email", they respond to it, GPT3 steps in and feeds a response into a new "email".

So how would I approach this? I think this could be pretty interesting as GPT3 hasn't been implemented in any games yet. I am aware that some beefy hardware may be required but my development computer is quite beefy enough.

P.S. Sorry if my title isn't specific enough, closest thing I could think of for this situation.

Comment: Presumably you've applied to use the OpenAI API? How have you tried applying it based on your research to date?

Comment: I used GPT2 on a Google Colab when that came out and played with it a bit, though I am not very experienced with OpenAI API. I wonder if it's possible to get GPT3 working in Unity.

Comment: Update: I signed up for the waitlist for OpenAI API. I am likely to use it if I get in.